# Use WebDeploy with Visual Studio Team Services Hosted Build Controller

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild, webdeploy, azure-devops

We have VS Team Services with a Hosted Build Controller. I want to use WebDeploy to deploy the build to my companies server once the build completes. The server I want to deploy to is not accessible publicly. Is there any workarounds to handle this without having to create an on premise build server?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Release Management for Visual Studio to do deployments. Its cleaner and more fit for purpose.

You can install it in an Azure VM and connect it up to Team Services. You can then have a local agent that pulls the files over http(s) to do the deployment. You need never expose your internal server.

Comment: Unfortunately our client doesn't have a Release Management license.  Could it be used for an on premise server or does it only work for cloud based servers?

Comment: It can be used on premises. Its included with your MSDN licences. I think you get one deployment target per MSDN Premium and 2 per MSDN Ultimate. Otherwise is circa $200 per deployment target. Server still included in TFS.

Comment: Thanks.  We are in the progress of setting an on premise server up to connect to VSO.  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: you now get one agent for free even with the free plan

Answer (score 0):

We have not found a workaround without exposing the deployment server publically, but did find the following approach very satisfying.

We are explicitly using an on premise agent so that we don't have to open anything up to the outside world, nor have to run any additional VMs in the cloud. The first on premise build agent you can run for free.

We are using this extension for the deployment 
[MSDeployAllTheThings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rschiefer.MSDeployAllTheThings) .

We did add a custom 'capability' to the on premise agent called 'onPremDeployment' to ensure that deployment builds do not run on the wrong agent ([configure agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/getting-started/configure-agents), look for capabilities).